# How to turn null into false in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator, isnull

In my code I have a `org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject` named `j`.
I want to read the property `use-name` from that Object:

```
Boolean isUseName       = (Boolean) j.opt("use-name");
```

The value can either be true, false or null (if the entry is not present in the JSONObject). Now I'd like to use `isUseName` for a conditional statement:

```
if(!isUseName) {System.out.println("No Name to be used.")}
```

This gives me a NullPointerException if "use-name" was not in the JSONObject. One way is to simply check first if `isUseName` is null, e.g.

```
if(isUseName != null && !isUseName) {System.out.println("No Name to be used.")}
```

I was wondering, if there is a more elegant way. Is it e.g. possible to (automatically) set `isUseName` to false, if `j.opt()` returns null? One thing that came to my mind is using a ternary expression, but this has a redundant `j.opt("use-name")`:

```
Boolean isUseName = (j.opt("use-name") != null)
                  ? (Boolean) j.opt("use-name")
                  : false;
```

Comment: Your ternary function is correct. Use that only..

Comment: A more elegant way does spring to mind, I'm guessing it's not applicable as it's "change your file ending to .groovy and use `if(isUseName)`" :)

Comment: If you're using java 8 you could use the `Option` monad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could compare with `Boolean.TRUE`:

```
boolean useName = Boolean.TRUE.equals (j.opt ("use-name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical expressions short-circuit, so if you check `null` first, then you can use it after the check:

```
if(isUseName != null && !isUseName) {
    // It's not null, and false
    System.out.println("No Name to be used.");
}
```

or

```
if(isUseName == null || !isUseName) {
    // It's null or false
    System.out.println("No Name to be used.");
}
```

and similarly

```
if(isUseName != null && isUseName) {
    // It's not null, and true
}
```

and

```
if(isUseName == null || isUseName) {
    // It's either null or true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about check if the key exists

```
boolean useName = j.has("use-name") ? j.getBoolean("use-name") : false;
```